# Fit any width x height image in Div box without compromising the width and height of the div box?

Tags: html, css, image

Ok.. I'm new.. Is there a way to auto "resize" an image into a div box so that the div box stays a curtain size even though the image may not be? and keep it responsive?

I'd like to just upload an image and not have to worry about resizing and cropping, and I'd like the image on the home page to all look the same size.

hope this make sense.. I can't seem to find anything

Comment: There are lots of solutions to lots of problems meeting those criteria - can we see some code? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to force the image to fit the size of the parent container, you could apply

```
background-size: cover;
```

to your css.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover` will work for background images. You'll want to use the proper cross-browser css for that, and your container will need to have a specified height, which you can change at your breakpoints to keep it responsive.

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

If you want to put the image in the div but not as a background image, you'll need to be looking at `overflow: hidden` on your container with fixed heights at your particular breakpoints.  This will of course require some work to position the image and make sure it scales properly.  The background image method is a much simpler approach.

Comment: I guess what I'm really trying to do is make the same size thumbnails for my front page so every post image is the same size. as of now they are all different because the images are different height's. I can get the width, just not the height.